# Can you select what release your scratch orgs are on

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

Summer preview came out Friday, is there a way to select the release you want.

I created a new scratch org and it was set to the version that production is on. Currently, that is Spring '19.  I would like to make a scratch org with Summer '19.

Answer (score 12):

This feature was added in Summer '19 ([release notes](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/summer-19-release-highlights/whats-new-lightning-platform-summer-19))

In your scratch org definition file (e.g. `project-scratch-def.json`)

```
{
  "orgName": "Example",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "release": "Preview"             // Preview, Current or Previous
}
```

Comment: @Eddie Any chance you can makr this accepted now?

Answer (score 0):

During every major Salesforce release, you have the opportunity to get early access to the release in your scratch orgs and sandboxes to test new customizations and features before your production org is upgraded. This window is called the Salesforce Preview, and scratch orgs created on the upcoming release are called preview scratch orgs.

For more reference : [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_version_selection.htm#:~:text=This%20window%20is%20called%20the,version%20as%20the%20Dev%20Hub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_version_selection.htm#:%7E:text=This%20window%20is%20called%20the,version%20as%20the%20Dev%20Hub).

Comment: This link is valuable, but at present the elements copied do not directly answer the question. Please [edit] to ensure the question is answered, and make sure to mark any text copied from the documentation as a quote using the editor.